# apache running but site not accessible

Tags: php, apache-2.2, ubuntu-9.10

Am pretty new to server administration. So I am not able to get to the root of the problem.

I am running Apache2 with mod_php on a 1GB Rackspace Cloud Server (Ubuntu 9.10). My site goes down often, and I have to restart apache2 to get the site working.

I checked the "error.log" file. There were no signs of any error messages. I even searched for words like [error] / error / warn / [warn] . But no results.

The site goes down and even then apache is running. When the site was down, the checked the status **/etc/init.d/apache2 status**  and it gave ** * Apache is running (pid 433). **

Any suggestions where I should look for the problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you found your solution? To date I having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

change your LogLevel to debug

Answer (score 1):

my experience is that virtual servers often run out of memory.
so you could reduce the amount of workers in your apache configuration.

also look into /var/log/syslog for OOM (out of memory manager) messages.

Comment: Nothing useful found in syslog

the workers config was:

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

Changed to 

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      15
    MaxSpareThreads      45 
    ThreadLimit          32
    ThreadsPerChild      15
    MaxClients          70
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

Please correct if I have overdone anything.
Thank you

Comment: no, looks fine...

Answer (score 0):

try /var/log/messages and search for httpd related ones.

Comment: in that file, i just have 4 lines regarding 'rsyslogd'
Something like - "rsyslogd was HUPed, type 'lightweight'."

Answer (score 0):

When the system goes down, what happens if you try and connect from the server itself? (i.e., use wget, curl, elinks, etc., to get the website from the same server's external address.  If that doesn't work, try the loopback.)  If either works, the problem is in your network - quite possibly a firewall.

Also check netstat -l to make sure that apache is still bound to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried issuing `strace -p 433` to see what Apache is doing? (where 443 is the actual PID of the Apache process, I'm assuming your PID has changed.)